# Migrating TagBuilder core methods from ASP.NET MVC 5 to ASP.NET Core (.NET 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, glyphicons, actionlink

I have a web app developed with ASP.NET MVC 5 and I have to migrate it to ASP.NET Core (.NET 5). I had some extesion methods for HtmlHelper to get glyph icon with a link:

```
public static MvcHtmlString GlyphiconActionLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string action, string controller, object parameters, string glyphiconTag, string title)
{
    TagBuilder span = new TagBuilder("span");
    span.MergeAttribute("class", $"glyphicon {glyphiconTag}");
    span.MergeAttribute("title", title);

    string url = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(
        null, action, controller, new RouteValueDictionary(parameters),
        helper.RouteCollection, helper.ViewContext.RequestContext, true);

    TagBuilder link = new TagBuilder("a");
    link.MergeAttribute("href", url);
    link.InnerHtml = span.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(link.ToString());
}
```

In Razor pages I could write this

```
@Html.GlyphiconActionLink("Details", "MyController", new { id = model.Id }, "glyphicon-pencil", "Show to details")
```

To get this HTML:

```
<a href="/mycontroller/details/1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Details" /></a>
```

Now, in .NET Core, this code doesn't work, it have many errors.

Changes I did:

- Return value from `System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString` to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString`, returning `return new HtmlString(link.ToString());`.
- From `link.InnerHtml = span.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing)` to `link.InnerHtml.Append(span.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing))`.

The errors I have are:

- `UrlHelper.GenerateUrl`: 'GenerateUrl' is inaccessible due to its protection level.
- `helper.RouteCollection`: 'HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'RouteCollection'.
- `helper.ViewContext.RequestContext`: 'ViewContext' does not contain a definition for 'RequestContext'.
- `span.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing)`: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments.

Do you know how to migrate it?

Comment: As a side note, have you considered re-writing as a TagHelper - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0 - this seems to be the new way of doing things.

Comment: This sort of thing:
https://github.com/Apress/asp.net-core-recipes/blob/master/AspNetCoreRecipes-master/Chapter04/Recipes01to09/Recipe09.TagHelpers/GlyphiconLinkTagHelper.cs

Comment: I tried it adding ```@addTagHelper MyApp.Web.Utils.GlyphiconLinkTagHelper, MyApp.Web``` in _ViewImports.cshtml, but the icon is not shown, I don't know if there is a problem with glyphicons in APS.NET Core 5

Comment: It is solved adding ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">```, but it is not very elegant. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/62518103/4600693

Comment: And this link also changes the style, so it is not a good solution

Comment: With TagHelper and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67490374/4600693 works.