# Use glyphicons in razor views in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, glyphicons, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm migrating an ASP.NET MVC 5 web app to ASP.NET Core (with .NET 5). In the previous web app I used glyphicons, but in the new one it seems that there are no available.

I created a new **ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)** project with .NET 5. I didn't change anything about bootstrap, it is v4.3.1, and if I use this HTML code `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> </span>` no icon is shown.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62518103/4600693), adding a link to v3.4.0 stylesheet, but this changes the style of the current web page.

Is it possible to use glyphicons in ASP.NET Core project without changing web's main style?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612690/bootstrap-4-glyphicons-migration is dropped in BS V4, Are you sure its working previously with BS v4

Comment: No, the previous version was v3.3.7. Do you know how can I use glyphicons in ASP.NET Core default project? In your link's answer speaks about scss, but in this project I have css files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a new CSS file, with the below style added into it. Then add a reference to the newly created CSS file in your asp.net core _layout.cshtml under the head tag.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="newglyphicon.css" />
```

---

```
@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');src:url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');}.glyphicon{position:relative;top:1px;display:inline-block;font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:1;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;}
.glyphicon-asterisk:before{content:"\2a";}
.glyphicon-plus:before{content:"\2b";}
.glyphicon-euro:before{content:"\20ac";}
.glyphicon-minus:before{content:"\2212";}
.glyphicon-cloud:before{content:"\2601";}
.glyphicon-envelope:before{content:"\2709";}
.glyphicon-pencil:before{content:"\270f";}
.glyphicon-glass:before{content:"\e001";}
.glyphicon-music:before{content:"\e002";}
.glyphicon-search:before{content:"\e003";}
.glyphicon-heart:before{content:"\e005";}
.glyphicon-star:before{content:"\e006";}
.glyphicon-star-empty:before{content:"\e007";}
.glyphicon-user:before{content:"\e008";}
.glyphicon-film:before{content:"\e009";}
.glyphicon-th-large:before{content:"\e010";}
.glyphicon-th:before{content:"\e011";}
.glyphicon-th-list:before{content:"\e012";}
.glyphicon-ok:before{content:"\e013";}
.glyphicon-remove:before{content:"\e014";}
.glyphicon-zoom-in:before{content:"\e015";}
.glyphicon-zoom-out:before{content:"\e016";}
.glyphicon-off:before{content:"\e017";}
.glyphicon-signal:before{content:"\e018";}
.glyphicon-cog:before{content:"\e019";}
.glyphicon-trash:before{content:"\e020";}
.glyphicon-home:before{content:"\e021";}
.glyphicon-file:before{content:"\e022";}
.glyphicon-time:before{content:"\e023";}
.glyphicon-road:before{content:"\e024";}
.glyphicon-download-alt:before{content:"\e025";}
.glyphicon-download:before{content:"\e026";}
.glyphicon-upload:before{content:"\e027";}
.glyphicon-inbox:before{content:"\e028";}
.glyphicon-play-circle:before{content:"\e029";}
.glyphicon-repeat:before{content:"\e030";}
.glyphicon-refresh:before{content:"\e031";}
.glyphicon-list-alt:before{content:"\e032";}
.glyphicon-flag:before{content:"\e034";}
.glyphicon-headphones:before{content:"\e035";}
.glyphicon-volume-off:before{content:"\e036";}
.glyphicon-volume-down:before{content:"\e037";}
.glyphicon-volume-up:before{content:"\e038";}
.glyphicon-qrcode:before{content:"\e039";}
.glyphicon-barcode:before{content:"\e040";}
.glyphicon-tag:before{content:"\e041";}
.glyphicon-tags:before{content:"\e042";}
.glyphicon-book:before{content:"\e043";}
.glyphicon-print:before{content:"\e045";}
.glyphicon-font:before{content:"\e047";}
.glyphicon-bold:before{content:"\e048";}
.glyphicon-italic:before{content:"\e049";}
.glyphicon-text-height:before{content:"\e050";}
.glyphicon-text-width:before{content:"\e051";}
.glyphicon-align-left:before{content:"\e052";}
.glyphicon-align-center:before{content:"\e053";}
.glyphicon-align-right:before{content:"\e054";}
.glyphicon-align-justify:before{content:"\e055";}
.glyphicon-list:before{content:"\e056";}
.glyphicon-indent-left:before{content:"\e057";}
.glyphicon-indent-right:before{content:"\e058";}
.glyphicon-facetime-video:before{content:"\e059";}
.glyphicon-picture:before{content:"\e060";}
.glyphicon-map-marker:before{content:"\e062";}
.glyphicon-adjust:before{content:"\e063";}
.glyphicon-tint:before{content:"\e064";}
.glyphicon-edit:before{content:"\e065";}
.glyphicon-share:before{content:"\e066";}
.glyphicon-check:before{content:"\e067";}
.glyphicon-move:before{content:"\e068";}
.glyphicon-step-backward:before{content:"\e069";}
.glyphicon-fast-backward:before{content:"\e070";}
.glyphicon-backward:before{content:"\e071";}
.glyphicon-play:before{content:"\e072";}
.glyphicon-pause:before{content:"\e073";}
.glyphicon-stop:before{content:"\e074";}
.glyphicon-forward:before{content:"\e075";}
.glyphicon-fast-forward:before{content:"\e076";}
.glyphicon-step-forward:before{content:"\e077";}
.glyphicon-eject:before{content:"\e078";}
.glyphicon-chevron-left:before{content:"\e079";}
.glyphicon-chevron-right:before{content:"\e080";}
.glyphicon-plus-sign:before{content:"\e081";}
.glyphicon-minus-sign:before{content:"\e082";}
.glyphicon-remove-sign:before{content:"\e083";}
.glyphicon-ok-sign:before{content:"\e084";}
.glyphicon-question-sign:before{content:"\e085";}
.glyphicon-info-sign:before{content:"\e086";}
.glyphicon-screenshot:before{content:"\e087";}
.glyphicon-remove-circle:before{content:"\e088";}
.glyphicon-ok-circle:before{content:"\e089";}
.glyphicon-ban-circle:before{content:"\e090";}
.glyphicon-arrow-left:before{content:"\e091";}
.glyphicon-arrow-right:before{content:"\e092";}
.glyphicon-arrow-up:before{content:"\e093";}
.glyphicon-arrow-down:before{content:"\e094";}
.glyphicon-share-alt:before{content:"\e095";}
.glyphicon-resize-full:before{content:"\e096";}
.glyphicon-resize-small:before{content:"\e097";}
.glyphicon-exclamation-sign:before{content:"\e101";}
.glyphicon-gift:before{content:"\e102";}
.glyphicon-leaf:before{content:"\e103";}
.glyphicon-eye-open:before{content:"\e105";}
.glyphicon-eye-close:before{content:"\e106";}
.glyphicon-warning-sign:before{content:"\e107";}
.glyphicon-plane:before{content:"\e108";}
.glyphicon-random:before{content:"\e110";}
.glyphicon-comment:before{content:"\e111";}
.glyphicon-magnet:before{content:"\e112";}
.glyphicon-chevron-up:before{content:"\e113";}
.glyphicon-chevron-down:before{content:"\e114";}
.glyphicon-retweet:before{content:"\e115";}
.glyphicon-shopping-cart:before{content:"\e116";}
.glyphicon-folder-close:before{content:"\e117";}
.glyphicon-folder-open:before{content:"\e118";}
.glyphicon-resize-vertical:before{content:"\e119";}
.glyphicon-resize-horizontal:before{content:"\e120";}
.glyphicon-hdd:before{content:"\e121";}
.glyphicon-bullhorn:before{content:"\e122";}
.glyphicon-certificate:before{content:"\e124";}
.glyphicon-thumbs-up:before{content:"\e125";}
.glyphicon-thumbs-down:before{content:"\e126";}
.glyphicon-hand-right:before{content:"\e127";}
.glyphicon-hand-left:before{content:"\e128";}
.glyphicon-hand-up:before{content:"\e129";}
.glyphicon-hand-down:before{content:"\e130";}
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-right:before{content:"\e131";}
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-left:before{content:"\e132";}
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-up:before{content:"\e133";}
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-down:before{content:"\e134";}
.glyphicon-globe:before{content:"\e135";}
.glyphicon-tasks:before{content:"\e137";}
.glyphicon-filter:before{content:"\e138";}
.glyphicon-fullscreen:before{content:"\e140";}
.glyphicon-dashboard:before{content:"\e141";}
.glyphicon-heart-empty:before{content:"\e143";}
.glyphicon-link:before{content:"\e144";}
.glyphicon-phone:before{content:"\e145";}
.glyphicon-usd:before{content:"\e148";}
.glyphicon-gbp:before{content:"\e149";}
.glyphicon-sort:before{content:"\e150";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet:before{content:"\e151";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt:before{content:"\e152";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-order:before{content:"\e153";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-order-alt:before{content:"\e154";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-attributes:before{content:"\e155";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt:before{content:"\e156";}
.glyphicon-unchecked:before{content:"\e157";}
.glyphicon-expand:before{content:"\e158";}
.glyphicon-collapse-down:before{content:"\e159";}
.glyphicon-collapse-up:before{content:"\e160";}
.glyphicon-log-in:before{content:"\e161";}
.glyphicon-flash:before{content:"\e162";}
.glyphicon-log-out:before{content:"\e163";}
.glyphicon-new-window:before{content:"\e164";}
.glyphicon-record:before{content:"\e165";}
.glyphicon-save:before{content:"\e166";}
.glyphicon-open:before{content:"\e167";}
.glyphicon-saved:before{content:"\e168";}
.glyphicon-import:before{content:"\e169";}
.glyphicon-export:before{content:"\e170";}
.glyphicon-send:before{content:"\e171";}
.glyphicon-floppy-disk:before{content:"\e172";}
.glyphicon-floppy-saved:before{content:"\e173";}
.glyphicon-floppy-remove:before{content:"\e174";}
.glyphicon-floppy-save:before{content:"\e175";}
.glyphicon-floppy-open:before{content:"\e176";}
.glyphicon-credit-card:before{content:"\e177";}
.glyphicon-transfer:before{content:"\e178";}
.glyphicon-cutlery:before{content:"\e179";}
.glyphicon-header:before{content:"\e180";}
.glyphicon-compressed:before{content:"\e181";}
.glyphicon-earphone:before{content:"\e182";}
.glyphicon-phone-alt:before{content:"\e183";}
.glyphicon-tower:before{content:"\e184";}
.glyphicon-stats:before{content:"\e185";}
.glyphicon-sd-video:before{content:"\e186";}
.glyphicon-hd-video:before{content:"\e187";}
.glyphicon-subtitles:before{content:"\e188";}
.glyphicon-sound-stereo:before{content:"\e189";}
.glyphicon-sound-dolby:before{content:"\e190";}
.glyphicon-sound-5-1:before{content:"\e191";}
.glyphicon-sound-6-1:before{content:"\e192";}
.glyphicon-sound-7-1:before{content:"\e193";}
.glyphicon-copyright-mark:before{content:"\e194";}
.glyphicon-registration-mark:before{content:"\e195";}
.glyphicon-cloud-download:before{content:"\e197";}
.glyphicon-cloud-upload:before{content:"\e198";}
.glyphicon-tree-conifer:before{content:"\e199";}
.glyphicon-tree-deciduous:before{content:"\e200";}
.glyphicon-briefcase:before{content:"\1f4bc";}
.glyphicon-calendar:before{content:"\1f4c5";}
.glyphicon-pushpin:before{content:"\1f4cc";}
.glyphicon-paperclip:before{content:"\1f4ce";}
.glyphicon-camera:before{content:"\1f4f7";}
.glyphicon-lock:before{content:"\1f512";}
.glyphicon-bell:before{content:"\1f514";}
.glyphicon-bookmark:before{content:"\1f516";}
.glyphicon-fire:before{content:"\1f525";}
.glyphicon-wrench:before{content:"\1f527";}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has dropped the Glyphicons icon font.If you need icons, some options are:
the upstream version of Glyphicons
Octicons
Font Awesome
For more details https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/migration/#components